# I can't get my data to display on my handlebars page

Tags: javascript, database, handlebars.js

So I'm able to save the data I'm trying to access into my database, it logs on the webpage upon it's event listener as well, with the correct value, half the data that I'm trying to display even shows up for every card, however, the other half of the data, while being stored, and console loggable, is not displaying on my webpage. I'm not even sure where to look or what to do at this point. If anyone has any recommendations, I'd greatly appreciate them!

```
{{#if RatingMovies}}
  {{#each RatingMovies}}
      <div class="column is-one-third">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <figure class="image">
        <img src="{{poster}}" alt="{{title}} Poster">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="media">
        <div class="media-content">
          <p class="title is-4">{{title}}</p>
          <p class="subtitle is-6">Type: {{type}}</p>
          <p class="subtitle is-6">Release Date: {{release_date}}</p>
          <p class="subtitle is-6">Rating: {{rating}}</p>
          <p class="subtitle is-6">IMDB Id: {{imdb_id}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
  <p>No rated movies yet.</p>
{{/if}}
```

my data for title, poster, rating, and imdb_id all display, however I receive nothing on my webpage for release_date and type

Comment: It might be helpful if you were to share the data you are passing to the template.